# is a teenager living in jeddah obliged to perform Hajj?

Tags: hajj

i am 17 year old girl still studying in school. I do not earn my own money. but since I live in jeddah with my parents, and the fact that I'm physically , practically comepeletely capable of performing hajj, Am i obliged to do it as soon a possible and will I be held accountable and Sinful if I do not perform it now?. or is it okay for me to delay it untill I get married or get a job for no valid reason.. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you are doing well. I am happy that you want to go to hajj. Keep up the good intentions and actions. May you do much more in this life and be rewarded greatly in the hereafter. Ameen.

In terms of hajj you should not delay it once you have set your mind to it. Who knows how long you will live. If you have the money and ability (i.e. health) to do it then you should do it.

> The Prophet (Peace and Blessings Be Upon Him) said: He who intends to perform hajj should hasten to do so. (Abu Dawud in the chapter of the rites of hajj)

With regards to the compulsory status of hajj we find in the Quraan that:

> In it are clear signs [such as] the standing place of Abraham. And whoever enters it [i.e., the Ḥaram] shall be safe. **And [due] to ALLAAH from the people is a pilgrimage to the House - for whoever is able to find thereto a way.** But whoever disbelieves [i.e., refuses] - then indeed, ALLAAH is free from need of the worlds. (Chapter 3 Verse 97)

And is a means to fulfilling one of the pillars of Islam in the following hadith:

> ALLAAH Messenger (Peace and Blessings Be Upon Him) said: Islam is based on (the following) five (principles):
>
> 1. To testify that none has the right to be worshipped but ALLAAH and Muhammad is ALLAAH Messenger (Peace and Blessings Be Upon Him).
> 2. To offer the (compulsory congregational) prayers dutifully and perfectly.
> 3. To pay Zakat (i.e. obligatory charity) .
> 4. To perform Hajj. (i.e. Pilgrimage to Mecca)
> 5. To observe fast during the month of Ramadan. (Bukhari in the chapter of belief)

And the the greatness for women doing hajj is that of jihad.

> Messenger of ALLAAH (Peace and Blessings Be Upon Him) said: "Jihad of the elderly, the young, the weak, and women, is Hajj and 'Umarah." (Nasai in the book of hajj)

**Conclusion**

Inshaa ALLAAH do your hajj as soon as possible as it is compulsory and when you are able you have to perform it right away. The evidence is in the five pillars of Islam. When it comes to fast you fast, when it comes to pray you pray, when it comes to pay zakat you pay if you meet the requirements. So the same is said for hajj when you are able to do so.

**Have a Nice Day!**